# Can't get AuthorizationMessageHandler in Blazor WebAssembly to work due to service lifetime issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I cannot get an HttpClient with AuthorizationMessageHandler working.

I have a project set up using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication package, and wired up for OIDC. That's working fine. Now, I want to make an http call to an API in another domain, using the access token provided during the OIDC authentication.

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-httpclient, this should be a simple task, but I'm having all sorts of problems with the service collection. Here's what I have to set up a typed HttpClient:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IAuthorizationClient, AuthorizationClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(authUrl))
   .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>().ConfigureHandler(new[] { authUrl }));
```

The issue here, for example, is that AuthorizationMessageHandler requires an IAccessTokenProvider in the constructor, which Blazor provides as a Scoped service. However, the HttpClientFactory is registered as a singleton service. When the HttpClientFactory tries to activate an instance of AuthorizationMessageHandler, it fails with the following error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler' from root provider.

Registering AuthorizationMessageHandler as a Singleton, I get:

> Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' from singleton 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler'.

Registering AuthorizationMessageHandler as a Transient, I get:

> Cannot resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'.

I'm out of ideas on how to get this to work. All the examples in the referenced link above don't appear to work.

I've tried this with both net5.0 and net6.0, with the same result.

Comment: Hi @Nathan A, It also works well in my project by following the official document. Could you please share more code?

Comment: @Rena, thanks for your help. Based on your request, I was rebuilding this from scratch in a new project so I could share the code, and turns out it worked. Slowly working forwards, I found the issue. Turns out, my Typed http client was coming from a nuget package that was referencing a 2.1 version of Microsoft.Extensions.Http, which is where AddHttpClient is defined. Explicitly adding the 5.0 version of that nuget to my project fixed the issue.

Comment: @NathanA - which package you made changes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error messages as you and I think it was related to me requesting the service that used the HttpClient before the user was authenticated.

My solution was to introduce a class as a mediator between the class that needs the HttpClient and the class that was used in the UI. That way **the service using the HttpClient is not requested from the service provider until the user has been authenticated** and then the IAccessTokenProvider can be resolved successfully.

I don't know if I'm just covering a bug with this solution, but it works.

Comment: hope we could have seen the code. I am having similar issue